# How to run an object map function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to run a recursive object map if `board.get('mode')` is **random**. Note that `board.get('random')` is simply a number between 0 and 2.

At the moment, its just prints the function out on HTML.

```
 displayTotal: function(){
    var sign = {
       'add': '+', 
       'minus': '-',
       'multiply': 'x',
       'random': function(){
            return sign[['add', 'minus', 'multiply'][board.get('random')]]
        } 
    };

    $('.game-info span.mode')[0].innerHTML = sign[board.get('mode')];
},
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with that code?

Comment: its part of a gaming screen that displays the respective math signs.  this is called everytime the user gets the answer right.  if they chose the random mode, it should change between add, minus, and multiply each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    var sign = {
       'add': function(){ return '+' }, 
       'minus': function(){ return '-' },
       'multiply': function(){ return 'x' },
       'random': function(){
            return sign[['add', 'minus', 'multiply'][board.get('random')]]()
        } 
    };

    $('.game-info span.mode')[0].innerHTML = sign[board.get('mode')]();
```

This makes all array elements functions which return the value you want.

The last line calls the function and passes the return value to innerHTML instead of the function itself.

Comment: okay got it. By the way, slight edit suggestion on the last line, think it should be `sign[board.get('mode')]();`